# How can I get the id of a container for a slick grid column during the onSort.subscribe event

Tags: javascript, html, slickgrid

I have a function in grid.js that looks like this:

```
grid.onSort.subscribe(function(e, args) {
  var actionItems = document.getElementsByClass("some-class");
   // some code here...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that any further code I place below this variable is applied to every grid on my page.

Each of my grids is contained within a div with an id.

```
<div id="grid1">....</div>
<div id="grid2">....</div>
```

I want to do something along the lines of this:

```
var actionItems = document.getElementById("grid1").getElementsByClass("some-class");
```

except that I want the getElementById to be able to get the calling element.  Maybe something like `getElementById(args.container.id)`

How can I do this?

Comment: you could possibly use the `grid.getUID()` instead, this won't give you the id but will give you something similar to query from. You should look at the lib code and see what you have available, you can discover a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Just note that in the generic event handler, SlickGrid always assigns the `grid` property of the `args` object to the calling grid.  This is to allow multiple grids to use a single event just as you describe.

So you can use  `args.grid.getUID()` to get the UID of the grid (as @ghiscoding said), and `args.grid.getContainerNode()` will give you the container DOM node.